# why does fdopen() modify the file permissions set by open()

Tags: c, linux, unix, system-calls

I am using a simple C program where I am setting the file permissions while creating the file to 0664 with `open()` and then passing the file descriptor to `fdopen()` and doing `fwrite()` into the file followed by `fclose()`. But to my surprise, I see the file permissions change to 0644 after the program completes the execution.

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>


int main (void)
{
    int fd = -1;
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    fd = open("/tmp/myfile.cfg", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_CLOEXEC, 0664);
    fp = fdopen(fd, "w");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Why do the file permissions get modified after the fd is handed over to `fdopen()`?  How can I preserve the permissions that I set in the `open()` call?

Comment: What's your umask?

Comment: Are the file permissions correct immediately after your call to `open`? Do the file permissions change after the `fdopen` call or the `fclose` call or only when the program ends? You should be able to test this easily by running your code line-by-line in a debugger while checking the file permissions in another terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file mode is set to the value of (664 & ~umask), where umask is a file mode creation mask, typically set to 022 by default. That is why your file permission is set to 644, because 0666 & ~022 = 0644; i.e., rw-r--r--.

In order to keep your desired permissions you have to set your process umask to 0000.

Docs for open: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

Search for `umask`.

How to set `umask`: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html

Or better, set file permissions by `chmod` after close. See comment by Andrew Henle below.

Comment: *In order to keep your desired permissions you have to set your process umask to 0000.* In general, that is not a good idea. First, the umask setting in professional environments is usually set for policy and/or security reasons. Second, the umask setting is a *process-wide* state and there is no way to modify it without introducing race conditions that can cause the original value to be lost. If your process must have specific permissions on a file, the **only** doesn't-affect-the-rest-of-the-process, race-condition-free way to do that is to explicitly set the permissions with `[f]chmod()`.

Comment: I used `chmod()` to set the file permissions and it worked as expected. But the description about the UMASK applies to `open()` call too,, right? However, if I modify my code to only have `open()` with 0664 and call `close()` the permissions are exactly as set in the call. Only when `fdopen()` is called the permissions change. Could you explain that?

Comment: When you `open` file with mode 664 it sets permission accordingly. When you call `fdopen` it uses default `umask` settings to set permissions. You can use `fchmod(fileno(fp), 0664);` after `fdopen`.